# RStudio Server crashed while reading large file

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

My session on an RStudio server had crashed while reading a large file. 
Only when I log in it uses a large amount of memory. The server is a linux machine (Ubuntu).

I can't see anything in the workspace. I tried to terminate the session, restart and kill the process from the terminal unsuccessfully.  I also removed the file I was reading, but it doesn't help.

It's stuck and doesn't seem that allows me to do anything.

Any suggestions what could I try to do?

Comment: When you restarted it does the workspace load up or does it just load forever?

Comment: sometimes loads something, but in general just loads forever. Sometimes it ask whether I want to terminate R session or keep waiting. When I choose terminate R, is when it partially loads something.

Comment: If you use windows, close it, find the rstudio folder in your appdata folder and rename it

Comment: I'm using linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

You ought to be able to get back to a good state as follows:

1. Quit your session, if you can
2. Rename your Rstudio folder: `mv ~/.rstudio ~/.rstudio-old`
3. If there is a file named `.RData` in your RStudio project's directory, remove or rename it, too
4. Start a new R session

The new session should come up clean, with no data or files.

Comment: I tried but it didn't seem to make any difference to me. I am using the server version rather than the normal one.

Comment: Hello from 2022. This helped me, thank you Jonathan!

Comment: I don't have a .rstudio folder, but I had some .cache in my home folder, and some other rstudio/project files in project folder. I renamed these to old, quitted the session. That seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by killing all processes in RStudio Server

```
sudo /usr/sbin/rstudio-server kill-all
sudo /usr/sbin/rstudio-server start
```

Then, deleting all history related files and directories from ~/.rstudio

After I started the RStudio Server session I waited a few minutes and eventually it came back and it allowed me to operate normally.